# exercise package: change the enumeration in environments by section

Tags: enumerate

What happens is that I use the "exercise" environment, but in section one they enumerate from 1-120 and in the next section (section 2) I need to enumerate again using the "exercise" environment, but this one starts counting from 121 and I want it to come out "1" again. What can I do? thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Sadly (but possibly not surprisingly), competent mind-readers and psychics are *not* known to frequent this site. Unless you provide some usable information about your document setup -- e.g., which document class do you employ? how or where is the `exercise` environment defined? -- odds than anyone can come up with a usable answer are rather poor.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [this](https://ctan.org/pkg/exercise?lang=en) exercise package. The package provides a command called `\renewcounter` in page 10 of the manual. You have to put the command `\renewcounter{Exercise}[section]`,
Note carefully the case and the brackets used. You have to put the command, preferably before `\begin{document}`. According to the manual, whenever the section counter is incremented the Exercise counter is reset to 0.